# Using @FindBy is displaying an nullpointerexception error message using Selenium - Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Im working whit Selenium and Java.
And i was doing a test to a web demo and was working fine, but now is displaying an nullpointerexception error, i though was something about using the @FindBy but using the WebElement is also failing, i think is something of the class where i do the methods,  i try with other question here but nothing works
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

This is my constructor

```
    public class PageObject {
    protected WebDriver driver;
    public PageObject(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);
        
    }
```

This is where search the elements

```
public class Home_Page extends PageObject {

    public Home_Page(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        
    }

    @FindBy(id = "nava")
    public static WebElement logo;

   
}
```

The page where i do the steps

```
public class Home_Page_Steps {
   
    public WebDriver driver;

   public void clickLogo(){
    Home_Page.logo.click();
     //driver.findElement(By.id("nava"));
   }

   
   
}
```

And the page where i call the methods

```
public class home_Page {

    public WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Home_Page_Steps hps = new Home_Page_Steps();
    
    @BeforeSuite
    public static void main(String[] args){
       //driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        System.setProperty("wedriver.chrome.driver", Utils.PathDriver);
    }

    @Test()
    public void openWebPage(){
        driver.get(Utils.BASE_URL);
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));
    }

    @Test(testName = "Click Logo")
    public void clickLogo(){
        openWebPage();
        hps.clickLogo();
        //WebElement logo = driver.findElement(By.id("nava"));
        //logo.click();
        //hps.clickLogo();
    }

    
    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `NullPointerException`, because you marked it as `static` field.

Static instances are initialized in Runtime before constructor or non-static fields. And they don't need class object to be created.

You declared `driver` as an class field, so when you get class static property, this field is `null` (static instance initialization block doesn't know anything about non-static fields).

[Java class member init order](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/order-execution-initialization-blocks-constructors-java/)

To initialize driver you need to pass it inside class contstructor in steps class and create new instance of `Home_Page` inside.

```java
public class Home_Page_Steps {
   
   private WebDriver driver;

   public Home_Page_Steps(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

   public void clickLogo(){
        new Home_Page(driver).logo.click();
   }
}
```